# Join two elements of one list to be in one index

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have a string which I formatted and then I split it using `|` character. Then the data between each `|`I am inserting into a list each with a unique index. Now I am trying to join two elements in that list so that they can be in one index.

Example

```
`List FruitSalad 

fruit.add("Apple")
fruit.add("Orange")
fruit.add("Tomatoes")
fruit.add("bananas")
fruit.add("Cucumber")

TextBox1.Text = fruit(0)
TextBox2.Text = fruit(1)
TextBox3.Text = fruit(3)
```

Typically `Apple` would have `index(0)` and `Orange` and `bananas` would have the `index(1)` and `index(2)` respectively. The thing is I want to join or merge `index(2)` with `index(1)` so that both elements would be merged in one index. e.g. `index(1)` has `Apple and Orange`.

How could I write it in terms of assigning it to a `TextBox.Text`, what would be the correct format for `TextBox.Text = fruit(?)`. I tried `fruit.Join(2)(1)` and `String.Join(result(2)(1).ToArray)` but that didn't work. Any suggestions? Regards.

Comment: Sorry Im' not fluent in vb.net In C#, I would write something like             String.Join(" ,",new []{fruit[0],fruit[1]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not concatenate the two

```
TextBox1.Text = fruits(1) & " and " & fruits(2)
```

or

```
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} and {1}", fruits(1), fruits(2))
```